# Prevent other domains from accessing my laravelApp

Tags: laravel

Since I opened my website that this domain: http://dreamhomeko.info, which is not mine, is accessing my full website: https://www.motocasiao.pt.

I have tried to use CORS plugin from barryvdh/laravel-cors.

I have tried in the AppServiceProvider the following code:

```
f(Request::getHost() != ("www.motocasiao.pt" || "beta.motocasiao.pt"))
            return redirect()->to(route('home'));
```

But it's like it didn't event work.

Could someone give me a hand on what's the best approach? I am using VestaCP and Larave 5.8.

Comment: Solved it using a custom middleware to filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a middleware "CrossDomain", and added it to the Kernel:

```
if(Request::getHost() != ("www.example.com" || "example.com"))
        return redirect()->to(route('home'));
```

Solved the issue!